# how to write an operation in a json file?

Tags: arrays, json, typescript, react-native, object

today i'm tryng to stylize my list of audiobooks but for doing so i have to make every object with an aspectRatio (key= value) in my json file but it gives me an error .
[image]

[image]

if i can't write like this in my json file how can i do it ?
thank you in avance

Comment: you can store the string `"aspectRatio": "150/200"` or the number resulting from the division: `"aspectRatio": 0.75 `

Comment: Your second problem might be the parser running out of sync. Say you added just "something": before the year. Just the key, without a value. So the parser thinks "year" is a value and should be followed by comma, and 1925 is a key and should be followed by a colon and so on.

Comment: thank you all i solve the issue and reach my goal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
...
"aspectRatio": { "width": 150, "height": 200 },
...
```

Or if the actual numbers don't matter:

```
...
"aspectRatio": 0.75,
...
```

Answer (score 1):

you can't do it, json is a data exchange format, not programable

the work-arround solution is:

```
import json
json_str = """
{
    "expr": "150/200"
}
"""
j = json.loads(json_str)
result = eval(j["expr"])
print(result)
```

but this may lead to security issue, if some body fill the value of expr as:

```
rm -rf /
```

that would be interesting

Comment: It also assumes a language with a javascript interpreter.